# Linked server Error on SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server

I have a linked server that is scheduled to run every 10 min. But I keep getting errors. "login timeout expired". Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Is the linked server working if you run a query from SSMS? Is there any error message on SQL Server log?

Comment: If you right click the Linked Server object and click Test Connection, does it report any errors?

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. You will have to add a lot more details if you want an answer from the community. E.g. linked server details (ommit sensitive information), network setup, accounts running the SQL Server Agent Jobs (domain or system account),  whether the accounts have access to the linked server, ... Hit the [edit] button and add as much details as possible to your question. Have a look at [ask] too. Thanks.